# Bot keeps showing the same error when kicked TELEPOT

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telepot

I've created a telegram bot that only prints the message that I send, everything works correctly until I block it or add/kick it from a group, when I do this the bot keeps showing this error: [image: 1]

Here's the code:

```
import telepot
from telepot.loop import MessageLoop
from pprint import pprint
import time

TOKEN="..."

def handler(msg):
    content, chat, id=telepot.glance(msg)
    pprint(msg)

bot=telepot.Bot(TOKEN)
bot.message_loop(handler)

while True:
    time.sleep(10)
```

I've also tried using the `getUpdates` function and it keeps printing all the messages, even the old deleted ones. I think that the problem is caused by "stored" messages but I don't know how to fix it.

I'm using:

- telepot version 12.7
- python  3.9.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope that you fixed this problem already.. But to help you or any future visitors I am sharing a simple solution.

`pip uninstall telepot`

`pip install telepota`

As telepot is not being maintained or updated since 2018 telegrams Bot API update raised the issue which is fixed in telepota. Telepota is a fork of Telepot which is Being updated timely.. Best part is you don't need a single change in your code..