# My telepot bor results kicked on my own chat with him

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telepot

I clicked on delete chat on the chat with my bot, thinking that this will only delete the messages, but after that when I try to start my bot this error shows off:
[image]

what can I do?

Comment: Same here. I use Telepot... some russian guy did the same thing and now i cannot start my bot anymore. revoked token, same thing.

Did you solve?

Comment: @SauZheR, i have created a new bot, you need to change the token in your code, I suggest you to delete your previous bot. You can do it from the fatherbot

Comment: It Is  not an option for me. I have some subscribers and they should rejoin :-/ For what i understood the problem Will repressent soon. Telepot Is no longer mainteined and telegram apis have changed. With Telepota i didn't  change a single line of My code.

Comment: @SauZheR so for you it had worked?

Comment: nope, changing token did not help in my case. I had to switch to other library `telepota`. Telepot is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution here:
[Bot keeps showing the same error when kicked TELEPOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66615066/bot-keeps-showing-the-same-error-when-kicked-telepot)

do install `telepota` instead of `telepot` with `pip`

byez

Comment: I can't test your suggestion, I have already opted for the shortest way and I deleted my previous bot for a new one, in this way I only need to change my token in the code and the game it's done